# Py2exe: the exe is created but if you run it you get a Runtime error R6034

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, gui2exe

I have made an application in wxpython, and I want to make it executable. All goes ok. All dlls needed are there, but when I try to run my exe I get the following error:

> Runtime error R6034, An application has made an attempt to load C 
>   runtime library incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, I fixed it by ADDING this text to the "manifest_template" string in setup.py (the advanced sample uses it)

```
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
        version="9.0.30729.4918"
        processorArchitecture="X86"
        publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"
        language="*"
    />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Please give some more information.If you have your code of setup it would be useful!!!Thanks

Comment: I just modified the sample code under 'advanced', you can find it in C:\Python2x\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\examples\advanced

Answer (score 0):

I've not had that issue. All my wxPython applications can be packaged into an EXE with no issues as long as I include the Microsoft DLLs. If you haven't already, make sure you set the bundle option to 3 instead of 1. I've had strange issues when using option 1. Also try running Dependency Walker on the generated EXE to see if it finds anything missing: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I use dependency and a bunch of dlls missing maybe that why it dont work