# Python executable getting a runtime error. R6034

Tags: python, executable, runtime-error, pyinstaller

I recently converted my wxpython script into an executable and ran them and I am getting a runtime error.  The error is about the C++ runtime library.  However this error doesn't seem to affect anything though.  I can just click out of it and my program runs perfectly fine.  Anyone know how to get rid of this error?

Edit:  After looking more into it from this thread: http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/py2exe-manifests-and-vc-redist-dlls-600827.html , it seems to be an error with the manifest file.  I found the file myProgram.exe.manifest. where exactly am I supposed to put it?  Also for the record I used PyInstaller to create the executable

Edit 2: Here is a link to the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIWPC.jpg

Edit 3: I tired dependency walker and got that two files were missing
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL

Where can I get those and where do I put them?

Answer (score 2):

If You Are using 3.3.0 then look under C:\Python33 or your python installation dir. You should find msvcr100.dll. Rename it to msvcr90.dll and the end. Try that!! Then try to recompile it to exe!!

Answer (score 0):

Similar:

- [Py2exe: the exe is created but if you run it you get a Runtime error R6034](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793742/py2exe-the-exe-is-created-but-if-you-run-it-you-get-a-runtime-error-r6034)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pyinstaller/AkU4pARcLUE

Try using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your exe to see if it's missing any DLL files.