# py2exe runtime error R6034 - "An application has made an attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly."

Tags: python, py2exe

Running an py2exe generated exe-file gives me the R6034 runtime error. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793742/py2exe-the-exe-is-created-but-if-you-run-it-you-get-a-runtime-error-r6034) one need to add something to a manifest_template, but what do i have to put in there? I've VS 11 installed.

Thx in advance!